# Repetitive code, can it be more efficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I have a number of functions for different ids that do much the same thing. I've tried to add it into a for loop but I'm hitting a closing issue. Can anyone help make this code less verbose?

```
var customColors = ["#000000", "#cc0000", "#2c53a0", "#e3580b", "#cc8900", "#4e9345", "#44b9be", "#8ed1e4", "#8a4593", "#68737a", "#2895d2"];

var customColorsShade = ["#000000", "#540000", "#142340", "#592205", "#543500", "#1E391B", "#1A474C", "#3A535A", "#361B39", "#2C2B32", "#103B54"];

$("#rect-id1").mouseover(function() {
    $("#pattern1 path").attr("stroke", customColorsShade[1]);
});
$("#rect-id2").mouseover(function() {
    $("#pattern2 path").attr("stroke", customColorsShade[2]);
});
$("#rect-id3").mouseover(function() {
    $("#pattern3 path").attr("stroke", customColorsShade[3]);
});
$("#rect-id4").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).attr("fill", customColorsShade[1]);
});
$("#rect-id5").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).attr("fill", customColorsShade[2]);
});
$("#rect-id6").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).attr("fill", customColorsShade[3]);
});

$("#rect-id1").mouseout(function() {
    $("#pattern1 path").attr("stroke", customColors[1]);
});
$("#rect-id2").mouseout(function() {
    $("#pattern2 path").attr("stroke", customColors[2]);
});
$("#rect-id3").mouseout(function() {
    $("#pattern3 path").attr("stroke", customColors[3]);
});
$("#rect-id4").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).attr("fill", customColors[1]);
});
$("#rect-id5").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).attr("fill", customColors[2]);
});
$("#rect-id6").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).attr("fill", customColors[3]);
});
```

Edited to add pen: http://codepen.io/sharperwebdev/pen/RWLypw?editors=001

Comment: can you please create jsfiddle or add SVG code ?

Comment: @Sharper I've updated my answer to include a modified version of your codepen

Comment: There could be a chance for CodeReview (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you are open for modifications and inputs!

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I know how much I have to learn so I'm always open to code review. Didn't actually know it was a thing on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one for loop.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++){
    $("#rect-id" + i).mouseover(function() {
        $("#pattern" + i + "path").attr("stroke", customColorsShade[i]);
    });
    $("#rect-id" + i).mouseout(function() {
        $("#pattern" + 1 + "path").attr("stroke", customColors[i]);
    });
    $("#rect-id" + (i + 3)).mouseover(function() {
        $(this).attr("fill", customColorsShade[i]);
    });
    $("#rect-id" + (i + 3)).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).attr("fill", customColors[i]);
    });
}
```

Slightly neater way by chaining the event binders:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++){
    $("#rect-id" + i)
        .mouseover(function() {
            var index = getIndex(this);
            $("#pattern" + index + " path").attr("stroke", customColorsShade[index]);
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
            var index = getIndex(this);
            $("#pattern" + index + " path").attr("stroke", customColors[index]);
        });
    $("#rect-id" + (i + 3))
        .mouseover(function() {
            var index = getIndex(this);
            $(this).attr("fill", customColorsShade[index - 3]);
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
            var index = getIndex(this);
            $(this).attr("fill", customColors[index - 3]);
        });
}

function getIndex(elem){
    return $(elem).attr("id").replace("rect-id", "");
}
```

Here it is working on your [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbaEBm?editors=001).

Edit: fixed for i getting changed:

Comment: Thanks for your time but it doesn't work correctly compared to the working, if verbose example I posted.

Comment: @Sharper should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks very much for your persistance James, It's perfect!

Answer (score 1):

use below code.

if you are using `<rect>` .  Here `$(this).index()` will give index of `<rect>` which start with `0`.

Also you can use `data-id` attribute to `<rect data-id="1">` and use `$(this).data('id')` instead of `$(this).index()`

```
$("rect[id^=rect-id]" ).mouseover(function() {
   if($(this).index() < 3){
      $("#pattern"+($(this).index())+" path").attr("stroke", customColorsShade[$(this).index()] ); 
    }else{
      $(this).attr("stroke", customColorsShade[$(this).index()] ); 
   }
});

$("rect[id^=rect-id]" ).mouseout(function() {
     if($(this).index() < 3){
       $("#pattern"+($(this).index())+" path").attr("stroke", customColors[$(this).index()] ); 
     }else{
       $(this).attr("stroke", customColors[$(this).index()] ); 
     }
 });
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. It's kind of what I'm after in principle but I dont think this will work in the situation. Here's a pen of what I'm doing: http://codepen.io/sharperwebdev/pen/RWLypw?editors=001  Thanks